# MongoDB Enterprise Advanced - Secondary/Backup Node Licensing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

A bit stuck on MongoDB licensing for their Enterprise Advanced version. Does anyone know if secondary/backup DBs require an additional subscription?

We've setup our DBs in the three-node format as recommended by Mongo but it would be a bit cheeky if that means that all three nodes need a subscription!

Assuming Ops manager installs don't require a subscription...(had not budgeted for this)

Thanks!

Mongo licensed on just the primary node.

Comment: That would very much depend on the specific terms of your subscription.  You should probably ask your MongoDB rep, or your company lawyer.